# Find $a$ such that the $P(X \in s) = 0.95$ where $ s = \{(x_1,x_2)^T \in \Bbb R : -a \leq x_1 \leq a \} $. Standard bivariate normal distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I have a bivariate normal distribution, where $ X = (X_1, X_2)^T$.
The means are given by $\mu = (0,0)^T$ and the covariance matrix is $ \sum = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$.

I've been asked to find $a$ such that the $P(X \in s) = 0.95$ where $ s = \{(x_1,x_2)^T \in \Bbb R : -a \leq x_1 \leq a , -a \leq x_2 \leq a \} $.

Here is my approach:
$P(X \in s) = \int ^a _{-a} \int ^a _{-a} f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2 = \int ^a _{-a} \int ^a _{-a} f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(x_2) dx_1dx_2 = (\int ^a _{-a} \phi (y) dy )^2$ where $\phi(y)$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution. This is because $X_1, X_2$ are uncorrelated standard normal variables, hence independent.

This equals $(2\Phi(a) -1)^2$. Setting this equal to $0.95$ and solving gives $ a = \Phi ^{-1} (0.98733...) = 2.236$ to (4sf).

Is this correct? The question is only 3 marks which makes me question whether I have overcomplicated this.

Thanks in advance!

(Also, the same question is given but instead where $ s = \{(x_1,x_2)^T \in \Bbb R : x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq r^2\} $. Do I approach this in the same way? Again this seems overcomplicated for a 3 mark question).

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. s is a square in the R^2 space. I've corrected it now.

Comment: For the second question where $s$ is a disk of radius $r$, converting to polar coordinates in the double integral will be helpful; see the [derivation of the Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Relation_to_random_vector_length).

Comment: You want the probability $P(X_1^2+X_2^2 \le r^2)$, for which you can either integrate using polar coordinates or you can use the distribution of $X_1^2+X_2^2$.